# Specific operators coloring Visual Studio Community 2017 C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, syntax-highlighting

Is there any way to change the coloring of specific operators in Visual Studio 2017 Community for C++ code.

Now when I go to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors and change the color of Operators every operator is changed including , { } ( ) [ ] || etc.

Is there any way that I can change the color of individual ones like f.e. = ?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I doubt that this is supported, mainly because it's crazy and nobody else ever wants to do it :)

Comment: I think it must be supported, even in old editors like `nano` you can do that (by changing the `nanorc` files).

Comment: Consider the situation you are reviewing someone else's code full of conditions and you doubt if they misspelled `==` with `=`

Comment: @am.rez There are compiler warnings for that, and static analyser warnings.

Comment: I believe it makes it more clear when you assign values or access class members.

Comment: The built-in syntax highlighter uses a lexer, not a parser.  Very fast, doesn't care about broken code.   Also pretty evident from the choices you get in the Options dialog.  Lots and lots of alternatives out there, have a look at the VS gallery.  Different colors for different operators, that ought to be tough shopping.

Comment: @InternetAussie agree, however some of them may be on purpose. By the way it helps reading the code.

Comment: @HansPassant disagree! It is hard to implement a fast syntax highlighter so users are picky!

Comment: You disagree that it will be tough shopping?  Well, good, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

C++ makes a good job of reusing operators for no reason and introducing ambiguity. It would be very nice to be able to highlight `=` differently when it is used in build-in assignment, custom assignment, constructor invocation, type alias declaration, namespace alias declaration, default argument declaration, default template argument declaration, default member function specifier, deleted member function specifier and whatever other random uses `=` have. And highlight it differently than `==`, `!=` etc.

You can try creating [MS connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio) suggestion, but it probably won't be implemented anytime soon.